# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL (PHP Version 5.6.17)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Really hoping someone can help with this as I just can't seem to resolve this issue.

I am having great difficulty with getting the code below to work on my website. 
The purpose of the script is to return car lengths based on a provided registration number.

The problem is when I move this over to my live environment the script simply won't work. Please can anyone suggest a possible resolution? I don't understand why It works absolutely fine in the development environment but when I attempt to run it on my main site I get the following error:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://website.com/CarLengthChecker.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://website.com/CarLengthChecker.asmx?WSDL"

```
 <?php

$carReg = "0000000";
try{

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$client = new SoapClient       ('https://wesite.com/CarLengthChecker.asmx?WSDL',
                         array('stream_context' => $context,
                               'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

$result = $client->GetVehicleDetails(array(
                                'VRM' => $carReg,

                                ));
print_r($result);
   }
       catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  ?>
```

I can access the WSDL address from a browser on the live server just not from the script.

I have checked the PHP settings on live and can confirm that both OpenSSL & SOAP
are enabled.

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Hi Long, yes I switched it over to use nusoap library. For whatever reason this resolved the issue.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Answer (score 0):

The resolution I found for this was to use the nusoap library (www.sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap). This problem may have been specific to our to live server environment but I would recommend attempting it if you are experiencing similar issues.